# Alignment tab character inside a starred command within align

Tags: align, starred-version

Here is a minimal example of what I want to do.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mylinebreak}{\@ifstar\@mylinebreak\@@mylinebreak}
\newcommand{\@mylinebreak}{&\\}
\newcommand{\@@mylinebreak}{&&\\}
%\let\mylinebreak\@@mylinebreak
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
 a&=b\mylinebreak
  &=c.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

This gives the error message

```
! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
\@@mylinebreak ->&
                  &\\
l.16 \end{align*}
```

What is wrong?  How can I get this to work?

Curiously, I get no error message if I remove the `%` or if I use `\mylinebreak*` instead.

I am guessing that the problem can be solved using the tricks involving master/balance counters, but I could not make this work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are defining `\\`  to look ahead for a `*` (incidentally the standard command already looks ahead for a `*`) but in doing this it "sees" the `&` and the next cell starts before the previous row is ended by inserting the original `\\`

The definition in `amsmath` is

```
\def\math@cr{\relax\iffalse{\fi\ifnum0=`}\fi
  \@ifstar{\global\@eqpen\@M\math@cr@}%
          {\global\@eqpen
             \ifnum\dspbrk@lvl <\z@ \interdisplaylinepenalty
              \else -\@getpen\dspbrk@lvl \fi
           \math@cr@}}
\def\math@cr@{\new@ifnextchar[\math@cr@@{\math@cr@@[\z@]}}
\def\math@cr@@[#1]{\ifnum0=`{\fi \iffalse}\fi\math@cr@@@
  \noalign{\vskip#1\relax}}
```

The special `` \relax\iffalse{\fi\ifnum0=`}\fi `` is designed to avoid this issue by preventing the halign template ending a cell at this point.

Note that it is already using `\@ifstar` to define `\\*` to prevent a page break at this point.

It is not clear what is the intention of using `&\\`  as the behaviour of that construct is the same as `\\`  as the empty cells do not do anything in almost all circumstances.

Comment: It also seems that the naïve xparse version of the OPs macro does seem to compile just fine

Comment: @David Carlisle Thank you very much for the answer.  My intention was slightly more complicated than the minimal example.  Perhaps I should have chosen a more meaningful example.

Answer (score 4):

### TL;DR

Simple solution: use a more robust check for the *-variant.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mylinebreak}{s}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{&x\\}{&x&=y\\}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
 a&=b\mylinebreak
  &=c.\\
 a&=b\mylinebreak*
  &=c.\\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I added something in order to better see that the choices are made correctly.

If you're running a version of LaTeX prior to the 2020-10-01 release, you also need `\usepackage{xparse}`.

### Analysis of the issue

Let's see what happens: `\mylinebreak` becomes

```
\@ifstar\@mylinebreak\@@mylinebreak
```

According to the definition of `\@ifstar` by `amsmath`

```
\def\@ifstar#1#2{\new@ifnextchar *{\def\reserved@a*{#1}\reserved@a}{#2}}
```

the above becomes

```
\new@ifnextchar*{\def\reserved@a{\@mylinebreak}\reserved@a}{\@@mylinebreak}
```

Let's see what `\new@ifnextchar` does:

```
\long\def\new@ifnextchar#1#2#3{%
  \let\reserved@d= #1%
  \def\reserved@a{#2}\def\reserved@b{#3}%
  \futurelet\@let@token\new@ifnch
}
```

so the expansions continues as (newlines just for reading convenience)

```
\let\reserved@d= *
\def\reserved@a{\def\reserved@a*{\@mylinebreak}\reserved@a}
\def\reserved@b{\@@mylinebreak}
\futurelet\@let@token\new@ifnch &
```

The trailing `&` comes from the fact that the newline after `\mylinebreak` is ignored during tokenization. Unfortunately, we're in an alignment, so as soon as TeX scans `&`, it inserts the *v* part of the template. And, indeed, the error message with a high value of `\errorcontextlines` reads

```
! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
\@@mylinebreak ->&
                  &\\
<to be read again> 
                   }
<template> }
            $}\ifmeasuring@ \savefieldlength@ \fi \set@field \hfil \endtempl...
<argument>  a&=b\mylinebreak &
                              =c.
```

and `\@let@token` is set to `}`. This is confirmed by injecting `\show\@let@token` at the beginning of `\new@ifnch`:

```
\@let@token=end-group character }
```

OK, let's go a step forward: the expansion of `\new@ifnch` yields

\ifx@let@token\reserved@d\let\reserved@b\reserved@a\fi\reserved@b

In our case, the `\ifx` test returns false, so we remain with

\reserved@b}&

and this breaks, because `\reserved@b` becomes `\@@mylinebreak`.

Comment: I just used ``\IfBooleanF{#1}{&} & \\`` saves a little typing

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanations.  I accepted the answer by Carlisle because I prefer more primitive solutions.